# ebay Inventory api listings shown as Out_of_stock even so I see a stock

Tags: php, json, ebay-api

I am using [ebay inventory api](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/inventory/resources/offer/methods/publishOffer) to manage ebay inventory.
I have recently made some changes to the already existing api functions I did not write. After ebay had some problem (confirmed ebay bug in developer board which got fixed) but killed most of our listings.
Now after some unrelated changes and some cleaning up of our db cause of no response because ebay closed the listings and not our functions. I can list inventory, create offers and publish these offers as it was working before I joined the comp.
However many / but not all of my published offers have a stock, yet they are shown as not available. in the UI
I can also see the stock in selling manager pro active listings, so I cannot filter for this error
When I edit the offer in the ebay UI I can see, that there is a stock and when I save it it tells me succesfully published. However the listings still appears to be not available after (yes, cache refreshed).

response of getOffer() call shows me that the

```
'listingStatus' => 'OUT_OF_STOCK',
```

Even tho it also shows

```
 'availableQuantity' => 8,
```

**Ebay Customer support:**
I am calling ebay customer support since last week, once someone told me its a bug and they are working on it but they dont have any information and I dont see anyone complaining about it in the developer boards(like with the bug before).
I just want to make sure I did not brakte something.

**Questions:**
Can I somehow update that listingStatus?
Do you know if this bug really exists or Customer support just wants me to stop calling them?

**GetOffer() response json:**

```
array (
  'offerId' => 'offerid',
  'sku' => 'sku',
  'marketplaceId' => 'EBAY_DE',
  'format' => 'FIXED_PRICE',
  'listingDescription' => 'Someproduct'
  'availableQuantity' => 8,
  'pricingSummary' => 
  array (
    'price' => 
    array (
      'value' => '71.75',
      'currency' => 'EUR',
    ),
  ),
  'listingPolicies' => 
  array (
    'paymentPolicyId' => 'xxxxxx',
    'returnPolicyId' => 'xxxxxx',
    'fulfillmentPolicyId' => 'xxxxxx',
    'eBayPlusIfEligible' => false,
  ),
  'categoryId' => '179680',
  'merchantLocationKey' => 'laatzen',
  'tax' => 
  array (
    'applyTax' => false,
  ),
  'listing' => 
  array (
    'listingId' => 'listingid',
    'listingStatus' => 'OUT_OF_STOCK',
    'soldQuantity' => 0,
  ),
  'status' => 'PUBLISHED',
)
```

Comment: What you want is to see if the `'availableQuantity'` is > 0? and if so make `'listingStatus'` what? Obviously not out of stock but what does it say if it's in stock?

Comment: its sais  'listingStatus' => 'ACTIVE'  or if the listing was closed it sais 'ENDED'

Comment: sometimes this error resolves itself with none of my script tuching the listing. I can see that in update history. e.g. the article I checked intesively before lunch and failed to set it active somehow is now active, but its last update was at 12 and when I wrote the post it was still Out_of_stock. But again only this and a few others, not all of the listings were this error was present

Comment: I don't know where to find out if the listing is closed, but I have added an asnwer on the out of stock part.

Comment: ebay first lvl support was also not able to change the quanitity so that it is active .... :D